# Java read utf-8 encoded file, character by character

Tags: java

I have a file saved as utf-8 (saved by my application in fact). How do you read it character by character?

```
File file = new File(folder+name);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
```

The two options seem to be:

```
char c = dis.readByte()
char c = dis.readChar()
```

- The first option works as long as you only have ascii characters stored, ie english.
- The second option reads the first and second byte of the file as one character.

The original file is being written as follows:

```
File file = File.createTempFile("file", "txt");
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

Comment: You've not specified an encoding, so some random platform specific configuration will be picked up (nice!). I strongly suggest replacing `FileReader`/`FileWriter` with `InputStreamReader`/`OutputStreamWriter` with an explict `Charset` and `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want a DataInputStream, that's for reading raw bytes.  Use an [InputStreamReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), which lets you specify the encoding of the input (UTF-8 in your case).

Answer (score 4):

You should be aware that in the Java world you use streams to process *bytes*, and readers/writers to process *characters*.  These two are not the same, and you should choose the right one to handle what you have.

Have a look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html to see how to work with characters in a byte-oriented world.

The Sun Java Tutorial is a highly recommended learning resource.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Reader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) (eg. [BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html))

Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

char c = reader.read();

Comment: The problem with this is that the `Reader` will use the default character encoding of the platform you're running it on, which might not be UTF-8. Use `InputStreamReader` as dmazzoni suggests, this allows you to specify that UTF-8 must be used.

Comment: Yes aware of that, but the file is being saved with the default encoding (by the same application). If UTF-8 is specifically needed then it should be specified in both places.

Comment: I'd recommend specifying the encoding as UTF-8, both when reading and writing.  That way there's no ambiguity and no possibility for mixups.

Comment: Yes I suggested specifying it in both places in my comment above (if UTF-8 is specifically needed)

Answer (score -1):

You can read individual bytes and when you hit a byte that is less than 128 (ie. the 8th byte is 0) then that is the last byte of the character.

I'm no Java expert, but I would assume that there are better ways. Maybe some way of telling the reader what encoding it is in...

**edit**: see dmazzoni's answer.